# How can I add DTO to List Object using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to add the Value object to List how can I do that.This is my DTO

```
public class Root    {
    public List<Value> Value { get; set; } 
    public Count Count { get; set; } 
}
public class Value    {
    public string Value1 { get; set; } 
    public string Value2 { get; set; } 
}

public class Count    {
    public int Total { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: `root.Value.Add(new Value() ...);` ?

Comment: please show the code that isn't working so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By following these simple steps:

```
// Create a Root object
var root = new Root {
    // Initialize the empty list
    Value = new List<Value>()
};
// Create a new Value object
var value = new Value {
    Value1 = "",
    Value2 = ""
};
// Add the value to the list
root.Value.Add(value);
```

Just a suggestion, when you have lists of something consider using plural (Values instead of Value)

```
public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
```

#### Edit based on comment

```
var valueList = new Root(); 

// Add this row
valueList.Value = new List<Value>();
valueList.Value.Add(new Value() { Value1 = "One", Value2 = "Two" });
valueList.Value.Add(new Value() { Value1 = "Three", Value2 = "Four" });
```

Comment: I am add item like this var valueList = new Root();
            valueList.Value.Add(new Value()
            {

                Value1 = "One",
                Value2 = "Two"
            });

Error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: You forget to initialize your list `Value = new List<Value>()` so it is null.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept useful answers!